# DataTable No data available in table first Load

Tags: javascript, meteor, datatables

I'm working with Meteor and I'm trying to display a data table using this code.

My JS:

```
onRendered() {

    $('#tableCarsWorkflow').DataTable({

        paging: true,
        searching: true,
        info: false,
        data: this.CarsList(),
        ordering: false,

        columns:
            [
     { data: "declaration.sg_art.numeroarticle", title: "Numéro de l'article" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_dec.quittance", title: "Quittance" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_art.bl", title: "Référence du BL" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_art.regime", title: "Régime douanier déclaré" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_art.nomenclature", title: "Nomenclature" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_art.description", title: "Description" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_art.num_colis", title: "Marque et numéro de châssis" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_art.Valeur_en_douane", title: "Valeur en douane" },
    { data: "declaration.sg_art.Pays_origine", title: "Pays d'origine" },
            ]
    });

    this.bindCarsListCLick();

},
bindCarsListCLick() {
    let self = this;

    $("#tableCarsWorkflow tr").bind("click", function (event) {
        console.log("click fired...")
        var dataTable = $(event.target).closest('table').DataTable();
        var row = dataTable.row(event.currentTarget);
        var rowData = row.data();

        if (!rowData) return; // Won't be data if a placeholder row is clicked

        $("#tableCarsWorkflow tr").removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        self.showDetails(true)

        self.workflowTable(_.where(self.WorkflowList(), { CarId: rowData._id }))


});
```

Html :

```
<template name="carWorkFlow">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="card-box">
                <h4>Liste des véhicules</h4>
                <table id="tableCarsWorkflow" class="table table-condensed table-bordered fixed-table-body"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

But when I load the page for the first time I get always the same message :
"No data available in table".

Comment: It is likely that the data is not present when you render the template. You need to pass the data using a Tracker computation or wait for the subscription via which you obtain the data to be ready before rendering the data table (given it is obtained via a subscription).

Answer (score 0):

Try data: CarsList().find().fetch()

Answer (score 0):

You sure that your this.CarsList() are returning the informations?
Put an console.log on first line of your onRendered to debug

```
onRendered() {
 console.log(this.CarsList());
 ...
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: How can I synchronize subscriptions ??

Comment: You can use the Template-Level Subscriptions approach.

Comment: Take a look on this example:

Comment: you put your subscription inside the onCreated Template.<your-template>.onCreated(function () {

Comment: I solve the problem by replacing onRendered function by autorun and adding this line of code :  $('#tableCarsWorkflow').DataTable({
                  destroy: true,